# Spring Data @Query with Pageable and Sort not sorting

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to specify a repository method annotated with `@Query` and a Pageable with a `Sort` object inside:

**Edit 1:** this repository is extending `PagingAndSortingRepository`.

```
@Query("...")
Page<Entity> findBySomething(..., Pageable pageable);
```

The `pageable` object is specified using the following method signature:

```
public PageRequest(int page, int size, Direction direction, String... properties)
```

But the output query is generated without the sorting options, example:

```
select a, b, c from table_x where ... limit 10
```

...while I was expecting something as:

```
select a, b, c from table_x where ... order by a asc limit 10
```

Has anybody here faced this sort of problem?
I'm using Spring-Boot 1.5.x.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, as I did.

Try this one, it could help you little.

1) In Controller

```java
@RequestMapping("/findUserByNameAndSortItDescNo/{name}")
public @ResponseBody Page<User> findBookByNameAndSortItAscByName(
        @PathVariable String name) {
    // Page = 'A page is a sublist of a list of objects. 
    // It allows gain information about the position of it in the
    // containing entire list.'
    Page<User> user = userRepository.findByName(
       name, 
       new PageRequest(0,100,new Sort(Direction.DESC,"no")));

    return user;
}
```

2) In Repository.

```
Page<User> findByName(String name,Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: which one? findByName? for this method, spring-data-jpa will create an implicitly hql query, not require @Query annotation.

Comment: What I meant is that I CANNOT use query by name, generated by Spring-Data,

Answer (score 1):

What does your request look like?

There is an unfortunately high indexed page on Google when you search for "spring boot sort pageable" which points you to this:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/paging-chapter.html

The above is no longer the right way to issue sorting. You should instead follow this https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/

The old way of sorting was adding an additional parameter with the same name postfixed by '.dir' with either asc or desc.

The new way is &sort=, where the direction is provided by an additional comma to the property name.

You can look at the returned result's "sort" value as well to see if sorting was ever attempted before checking the back-end query generation.  i.e.

> {"content":[],"last":true,"totalElements":0,"totalPages":0,"sort":[{"direction":"DESC","property":"createdDate","ignoreCase":false,"nullHandling":"NATIVE","ascending":false,"descending":true}],"size":1000,"number":0,"first":true,"numberOfElements":0})

I hope this helps.

Comment: "The new way is &sort=, where the direction is provided by an additional comma to the property name." Was the trick I was missing.